# How to find the taylor series for $f(x) = \frac{1}{16-x^2}$ centered at 9 in summation notation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Having trouble finding the taylor series for the following function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{16-x^2} \textrm{  centered at c=9}$$

I was trying to look at it in a way such that I could modify $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$. I wasn't able to come up with anything though.

I found some of the first few terms, but I can't see to find all the patterns.

$$\frac{1}{16-x^2} = \frac{-1}{65} + \frac{18}{4225}(x-9) - \frac{518}{274625}(x-9)^2$$

I noticed the denominators multiply by 65 each time. Can't seem to find a pattern for the numerator though.

Seems to be something like:

$$2x = 2(9) = 18$$

$$6x^2 + 32 = 6(9^2) +32 = 518$$

$$24x^3 + 384x = \textrm{next numerator}$$

Pattern doesn't seem to stay much or gets more complex though. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Write
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = \frac{1}{16-x^2}\\
& = \frac{1}{8}\left[\frac{1}{4-x}+\frac{1}{4+x}\right]\\
& = \frac{1}{8}\left[\frac{1}{-5-(x-9)}+\frac{1}{13+(x-9)}\right]\\
& = \frac{1}{8}\left[\frac{1}{-5}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-9}{5}}\right)+\frac{1}{13}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-9}{13}}\right)\right]\\
& = \frac{1}{-40}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-9}{5}}\right)+\frac{1}{104}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-9}{13}}\right)
\end{align*}
Now use the geometric series expansion 
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-a}{b}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)^k,$$
to get,
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = \frac{1}{-40}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-9}{5}}\right)+\frac{1}{104}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-9}{13}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{-40}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{x-9}{5}\right)^k+\frac{1}{104}(-1)^k\left(\frac{x-9}{13}\right)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{(-40)5^k}+\frac{1}{(104)13^k}\right)(x-9)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\frac{(-1)^k}{8}\left(\frac{5^{k+1}-13^{k+1}}{65^{k+1}}\right)}(x-9)^k\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Actually the numerator of the fraction must be $5^{k+1}-13^{k+1}$.

Comment: @RicardoLargaespada Thanks for pointing out the the typo. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Decompose:
$$\frac{1}{16-x^2}=\frac{1}{(4-x)(4+x)}=\frac18\left[\frac1{4-x}+\frac1{4+x}\right]$$
Expand each term separately:
$$\begin{align}f(9)&=\frac1{4-9}=-\frac15; \\
f'(9)&=\frac1{(4-9)^2}=\frac1{5^2};\\
f''(9)&=-\frac2{(4-9)^3}=-\frac2{5^3};\\
&\vdots\\
\frac1{4-x}&=-\frac15+\frac{1}{1!\cdot 5^2}(x-9)-\frac2{2!\cdot 5^3}(x-9)^2+\cdots+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1)!\cdot 5^{n+1}}(x-9)^n+\cdots\\
=====&========================================== \\
f(9)&=\frac1{4+9}=\frac1{13};\\
f'(9)&=-\frac1{(4+9)^2}=-\frac1{13^2};\\
f''(9)&=\frac2{(4+9)^3}=\frac2{13^3};\\
&\vdots\\
\frac1{4+x}&=\frac1{13}-\frac{1}{1!\cdot 13^2}(x-9)+\frac2{2!\cdot 13^3}(x-9)^3+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1)!\cdot 13^{n+1}}(x-9)^n+\cdots\\
\end{align}$$
Hence:
$$\begin{align}\frac1{16-x^2}&=\frac18\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}(x-9)^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{13^{n+1}}(x-9)^n\right]=\\
&=\frac18\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{65^{n+1}}\left[(-1)^{n+1}13^{n+1}+(-1)^n5^{n+1}\right](x-9)^n=\\
&=\frac18\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 65^{-n-1}\left[(-13)^{n+1}+(-1)^n5^{n+1}\right](x-9)^n.
\end{align}$$
See [WolframAlpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%201%2F(16-x%5E2)%20for%20x%3D9).